# Javascript: How to change image src dynamically with event on buttonclass?

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

I have some problems writing a function which changes the image dynamically. I have three buttons: Small, Medium and Large.

When I press a button I want the image to change to the preferred size. The HTML of the buttons cannot be changed, so I want to write a JS function which makes this possible.

Beneath you see my script:

```
<img src="" style="width:100%; height:400px;" name="formula" id="formula">

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    changeClass();

    document.getElementsByClassName("button-variable-item")[0].addEventListener( 'click', changeClass);
    document.getElementsByClassName("button-variable-item")[1].addEventListener( 'click', changeClass);
    document.getElementsByClassName("button-variable-item")[2].addEventListener( 'click', changeClass);

});

function changeClass(){
    console.log('binnen');

    var image_name;
    var L = document.getElementsByClassName("button-variable-item-l");
    var S = document.getElementsByClassName("button-variable-item-s");
    var M = document.getElementsByClassName("button-variable-item-m");

    if ( S[0].classList.contains('selected') ){
        image_name = "https://www.studio-31.nl/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/WhatsApp-Image-2018-03-16-at-11.52.31.jpeg";
        console.log('S');
    }else if ( L[0].classList.contains('selected') ){
        image_name = "https://www.studio-31.nl/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/WhatsApp-Image-2018-03-16-at-11.52.19.jpeg";
        console.log('L');
    }else if ( M[0].classList.contains('selected') ){
        image_name = "https://www.studio-31.nl/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/WhatsApp-Image-2018-03-16-at-11.46.25.jpeg";
        console.log('M');
    }

     $('#formula').attr('src', image_name);
}

</script>
```

And here you find the HTML of the buttons:

```
<ul class="list-inline variable-items-wrapper button-variable-wrapper " data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_size">
<li data-wvstooltip="L" class="variable-item button-variable-item button-variable-item-l selected" title="L" data-value="l">
    <span>L</span>
</li>
<li data-wvstooltip="M" class="variable-item button-variable-item button-variable-item-m" title="M" data-value="m">
    <span>M</span>
</li>
<li data-wvstooltip="S" class="variable-item button-variable-item button-variable-item-s" title="S" data-value="s">
<span>S</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

When the I press on a button it does something, but not the expected action..

Please help me out!

Comment: And what is that something? It would be helpful to tell us what problem you're experiencing. Does `image_name` end up with a value that's expected?

Comment: u can create a img element with the same src for the img and the for which case apply to the var(img).style.width=0%; ..50%; ...100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your code by setting the `selected` class to the clicked element before you do your thing.

```
function changeClass()
{
    console.log('binnen');

    //check if function is called from button binding
    if($(this).is('.button-variable-item')) {
        //remove selected class from every button
        $('.button-variable-item').removeClass('selected');
        //add selected class to the clicked button
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }

    [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<li data-wvstooltip="L" data-src="image-url-l">
    <span>L</span>
</li>
<li data-wvstooltip="M" data-src="image-url-m">
    <span>L</span>
</li>
<li data-wvstooltip="S" data-src="image-url-s">
    <span>L</span>
</li>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", "li", function(){
 $("#formula").attr("src", $(this).attr("data-src"));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `event` argument to the `changeClass` function. This will let you detect the button the event was emitted from.

```
function changeClass(event) {

    switch (event.target.getAttribute('data-value')) {

       case 'l': ....
```